# Is there any way to exit Berserk Mode?

Tags: nier-automata

While playing as

> A2

I can engage "Berserk Mode", which very rapidly drains my HP but lets me do a lot more damage. This is cool and all, but is it possible to exit Berserk Mode? I blew through 30 Medium Recoveries and 60+ Large Recoveries in about a 5-10 minute span. Since I can only hold 99 of each type of Recovery item, this is very clearly unsustainable.

Pressing and holding L3 + R3 engages Berserk Mode, the same way the other playable characters Self-Destruct. However, pressing and holding L3 + R3 does *not* cancel out Berserk Mode.

So far, the only way I've found to cancel Berserk Mode is to get into an Access Point and Transport to another area. Is there any other way to get out of Berserk Mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently my fear of death hid the answer from me.

Based on posts in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168677-nier-automata/75123554), running out of health in Berserk Mode *doesn't actually kill you*. If you run out of health, it will exit Berserk Mode and leave you with 1HP.

> Berserker mode really is a blast, **but it only lasts for .. 5 seconds?**

---

> Auto Item will make it so she instantly heals **after B mode ends**

---

> **As soon as it ends i will immediately hea**l, but healing WHILE in berserker mode isn't the best idea if i can be honest. I can either Dodge or heal, and **considering that one shot will drop me dead** (unless my Reset +6 blesses me) i'd rather focus on outputting damage than focussing on healings..

---

> It is percent based, but so is the amount you heal from sources. **The amount of time it takes to drain to 1** should be the same, which means less HP takes the same amount of time as a lot but the amount you can heal off Damage Heal is what makes or breaks B Mode

Letting your health run out seems to be the intended way to exit Berserk Mode. Using an Access Point to Transport to another one appears to be a workaround to end it "early" without dropping to 1HP.